# How to detect when the player presses the % key?

Tags: java, input, keyboard

I want to use the "%" (percent) sign to do something in my game.

I tried checking for `KeyEvent.VK_DOLLAR` but nothing happened. But it works perfectly with for example "I" as an input key, so I know the rest of the code should work.

I'd like to know how to handle these types of key events in Java.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37605628/3064164)?

Comment: @DMGregory Yes thank you!